# in Delphi I want to replace the "Tform3.ListBox" in "Tform3.Listbox.Clear" with a parameter. What datatype do I have to put there?

Tags: delphi, types, parameters, procedure

For my procedure I wanted to put the identifier as a parameter, but I dont know what datatype to use that knows the .clear method or is usable on a TListBox. In this example I used string but that obviously doesn't work.

```
procedure Reset(input, output: string);
begin
     input := '';
     output.Clear;
```

"input" is my Edit.text, so I can just use string for that, but "output" is my ListBox.

my entire code is

```
unit UFunction;

interface
uses
  System.Classes,System.StrUtils,System.AnsiStrings,System.SysUtils;

 procedure CaseSensitiveSwitchFlip ;
 procedure CopyToClipboard;
 procedure Reset(Input: string; Output: string);
 procedure Sort(input: string);
implementation

uses
UInterface, Vcl.Clipbrd;

procedure CaseSensitiveSwitchFlip ;
begin
     IstCaseSensitiveActive := not IstCaseSensitiveActive
end;

procedure CopyToClipboard;
begin
     ClipBoard.AsText := Form3.ListeLb.Items.Text;
end;

procedure Reset(input: string; output: string);
begin
     input:='';
     output:= '';
end;

procedure Sort(input: string);
var
ArrayIndex, inputIndex, Count: integer;
Character: array[1..256] of string;
text: string;
begin
     if (input<>'') then begin
       if (input<>'') and (Form3.ListeLb.Items.Count <> 0)  then
         Form3.ListeLb.Clear;
       ArrayIndex:= 0;
         repeat
               if input<>'' then begin
                 ArrayIndex:= ArrayIndex +1;
                 if not IstCaseSensitiveActive then
                   input:= AnsiUpperCase(input);
                 Character[ArrayIndex]:= input[1];
                 Count:= 1;
                 inputIndex:= 0;
                 text:= (input);
                 delete(text, 1, 1);
                 input:= text;
                 if AnsiContainsStr(input, Character[ArrayIndex]) and (Character[ArrayIndex] <> ' ') then begin
                   repeat
                         inputIndex:= inputIndex +1;
                         if Character[ArrayIndex] = input[inputIndex] then begin
                           Count:= Count + 1;
                           text:= input;
                           delete(text, inputIndex, 1);
                           input:= text;
                           inputIndex:= inputIndex - 1;
                         end;
                   until not (AnsiContainsStr(input, Character[ArrayIndex])) or (Character[ArrayIndex] = ' ');
                   Form3.ListeLb.Items.Add(Character[ArrayIndex] + ': ' + IntToStr (Count))
                 end
                 else if (Character[ArrayIndex] <> ' ') then begin
                        Form3.ListeLb.Items.Add(Character[ArrayIndex] + ': ' + IntToStr (Count))
                 end;
               end;
         until (length(input) = 1) or (input = '');
         if input <> '' then begin
           ArrayIndex:= ArrayIndex + 1;
           Character[ArrayIndex]:= input[1];
           input := '';
           if Character[ArrayIndex] <> ' ' then
             Form3.ListeLb.Items.Add(Character[ArrayIndex] +': ' + IntToStr (1));
         end;
     end
end;

end.
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you please provide your real code.

Comment: Write something like this: `procedure Reset(Input: TEdit; Output: TListBox);` And work inside this method with `Input.Text` and `Output.Clear`. By the way: [ask]

Comment: *"What datatype do I have to put there?"* What type is `TForm3.ListBox`? That type.

Comment: @Dima Sorry for forgetting to give my declaration. But even with

procedure Reset(Input: TEdit; Output: TListBox)

as my declaration it doesnt work. I get Undeclared identifier on every TEdit and TlistBox, and the other 2 errors are saying that TEdIt doesnt contain an element called text and TLIstBox doesnt contain an element called clear.

Comment: Alright, show us the *full* code you want to adapt to work with `TEdit` and `TListBox`. Because from you last comment I can't get what goes wrong with my  suggestion.

Comment: My full code is here: https://pastebin.com/eXCgRG3k sorry, I dont know how to use this website much.

Comment: There is a link-button below your question that is labeled `Edit`. Click it and add your code to your question. It will help to store your code even if `pastebin` will be unavailable for some reasons.

Comment: What I see in your code is that you forgot to add `Vcl.StdCtrls` unit to uses clause of your unit. That's why you had those errors `TEdit` is not found etc. Add this unit and try my suggestion again. It should works now.

Comment: @Dima ah yes, it works now! Thank you so much and thank you for being patient with me!

Answer (score 1):

You have to simply change types of paramter input to TEdit output to TListBox

```
procedure reset(input:TEdit; output:TListBox)
begin
 input.Text:='';
 output.items.clear;
end;
```

A lot of time passed when I saw pascal not object code without classes;